# firebase setvalue crash android studio

Tags: android, firebase

I have class

```
    public class Expense{
        public String date;
        public String item;
        public int price;
        public Expense(){}
        public Expense(String date,String item,int price){
            this.date = date;
            this.item = item;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        public void setItem(String item){
            this.item = item;
        }
        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public String getItem() {
            return item;
        }
     }
```

and a function

```
public void createByDB(String[] data,int[] price ,int size,int[] pick){
    //String []data looks like ={"apple","banana","candy"....}
    //int []price looks like ={18,20,25,....}
    //size = the size of int[] pick
    //int[]pick looks like = {0,1,4,...} ,the numbers in this array is randomly pick,and the number won't excess the size of data and price
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("details");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        Expense expense = new Expense(date,data[pick[i]],price[pick[i]]);
        myRef.push().setValue(expense);
    }
}
```

I don't know why if I call createByDB() would crash my program

I checked my Logcat and found error message

> 2018-10-14 12:21:13.832
>   2236-27737/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization
>   check failed with status -12. 2018-10-14 12:21:13.832
>   2236-27737/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native
>   AudioRecord object.

I googled it , the posts say I must add RECORD_AUDIO permission  to my AndroidManifest.xml
so I added this line into my manifest
[this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiJXc.png)

**Update** This is my AndroidManifest.xml[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBKKb.png)

but my program still crash when I call createdByDB()

I don't know where I did it wrong.  Can someone give me any advice? Thank you!

**Update:**
If I edit

```
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        Expense expense = new Expense(date,data[pick[i]],price[pick[i]]);
        myRef.push().setValue(expense);
    }
```

to this

```
        Expense expense = new Expense(date,data[1],price[1]);
        myRef.push().setValue(expense);
```

it works , I have tried

```
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)System.out.println("pick:"+pick[i]);
```

to check whether I excess the size of data and price ,but the answer is no

so, how can I revise my program to do what I want ?

Comment: Those logs seem to be for a different app, and the code you've posted doesn't require the RECORD_AUDIO permissions. Could select "Show only selected application" from the drop-down menu in the `logcat` window? It should be in the top right corner.

Comment: @TheGamer007 oh I found my error, both  size of data and price is 35 but my pick array sometimes have the number '35' in it . So excess the size of array. Thank you. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
as well to record and save audio.

Those lines are not enough Android 6.0 and higher devices. Please add this type of permission request for your application before do any recording related things.

```
    private void checkPermissions() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

    }

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1:
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 2);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try that check permission and request permission methods?

Comment: and... I don't have any function about recording in my whole program , I don't know why the error message shows AudioRecord.

Comment: I have updated my details about my AndroidManifest.xml in my post

Comment: for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
  if( data.length > pick[i] && price.length > pick[i]){

   Expense expense = new Expense(date,data[pick[i]],price[pick[i]]);
         myRef.push().setValue(expense);
  }
    }